# Synchronizing on-prem PostgreSQL raster database with AWS RDS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a folder of rasters that updates daily that I load into a PostgreSQL database using the raster2pgsql command line tool. I want to make this database outward facing so that I can connect to it. I like the idea of storing this database on AWS, but I don't know if it's possible to

1. Add rasters directly to the AWS PostgreSQL database, or
2. Sync my on-prem database with the database on AWS.

I really would like to avoid having to re-import the entire database daily as I only need to keep adding one raster per day. Is this possible (and how would I go about doing this?) or is there a better tool for doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're storing your rasters *in* the database versus the external storage option?

Comment: @DPSSpatial correct, I'm not currently aware of a way to directly load rasters into external storage

Comment: OK Thanks - would a SQL dump work on rasters as well?

Comment: Is it possible to only dump part of a database?

Comment: Yes - but will it work on a raster? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3682944/1704448

Comment: @DPSSpatial I think that should work. If you wanna add it as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: ok great! Let me know if it works, we can tweak the answer if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pg_dump and specify a single table to export:

```
pg_dump --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --format plain --verbose --file "<abstract_file_path>" --table public.tablename dbname
```

From there, pg_restore can be used to upload that table to your AWS server.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682866/how-to-create-a-backup-of-a-single-table-in-a-postgres-database/3682944#3682944